# Node looping function code failing due to undefined data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm running some simple JS using node on some data to basically transform it.

When I run the data through my function once, it works as intended, but the moment I run it through again to do another transformation it would throw a JS error as the data I send through again, or part of it, seems to be `undefined`, but I can't figure out why!

My JS file has the code below. All it is doing is taking the input data, locate some HTML like `<span style="font-size: 24px">Some Text</span>`, isolate it, take the `Some Text`, wrap it in `======` and then replace in the input data the HTML with the transformed code.

My input data has many instances of that span HTML which I want to clean/transform.

```
// input & output
var readline = require("readline");
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});
var i = 0;
var strings = [];

// HTML cleaner
function processHTML(line, openingTag, closingTag, mdStart, mdEnd) {
  var openTagIndex = line.indexOf(openingTag);
  var closeTagIndex = line.indexOf(closingTag);
  var closeTagLength = closingTag.length;
  var htmlTag = line.substring(openTagIndex, closeTagIndex + closeTagLength);

  var content = htmlTag.split(openingTag)[1];
  content = content.split(closingTag)[0];

  return line.replace(htmlTag, mdStart + content + mdEnd);
}

// process left over HTML
function processLine(line) {
  if (line.indexOf("font-size: 24px;") > 0) {
    // heading 1
    return processHTML(
      line,
      '<span style="font-size: 24px;">',
      "</span>",
      "======",
      "======"
    );
  }

  return line;
}

// loop through lines
rl.on("line", function(line) {
  strings[i] = line;
  i++;
}).on("close", function() {
  var data = strings.join("");

  data = processLine(data);
  // data = processLine(data);

  process.stdout.write(data);
});
```

My input data looks like this:

```
<div id="en-note"><div>Sunday 5.6.16</div><div><br/></div><div>Money &amp; charity services I need to stop before leaving.</div><div><br/></div><div>Do this during or at latest by end of June.</div><div><br/></div><div><span style="font-size: 24px;">Services</span></div><ol><li><div>Netflix <span style="background-color: rgb(255, 250, 165);-evernote-highlight:true;">???</span></div></li><ol><li><div><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 250, 165);-evernote-highlight:true;">cancel</span></div></li></ol><li><div>US DNS <span style="background-color: rgb(255, 250, 165);-evernote-highlight:true;">???</span></div></li><ol><li><div><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 250, 165);-evernote-highlight:true;">cancel</span></div></li></ol><li><div>Drama Fever <span style="background-color: rgb(255, 250, 165);-evernote-highlight:true;">???</span></div></li><ol><li><div><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 250, 165);-evernote-highlight:true;">cancel</span></div></li></ol><li><div>Crunchy Roll</div></li><ol><li><div><span style="font-weight: bold;">CANCELLED</span></div></li></ol></ol><div><br/></div><div><span style="font-size: 24px;">Christian</span></div><ol><li><div>City Bible Forum $100 support</div></li><ul><li><div><span style="font-weight: bold;">DONE</span> - June 4 &gt; <span style="font-weight: bold;">CANCELLED, TAX RECEIPT </span></div></li><li><div>&quot;ecom Sydney&quot;</div></li></ul><li><div>Youth For Christ $100 support</div></li><ul><li><div><span style="font-weight: bold;">DONE</span> - June 20 &gt; <span style="font-weight: bold;">CANCELLED, TAX RECEIPT </span></div></li><li><div>&quot;YOUTH FOR CHRIST AUSTR MITCHAM VIC&quot;</div></li></ul><li><div>Phil ministry $100 support</div></li><ul><li><div><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 250, 165);-evernote-highlight:true;">FINISH after September payment</span></div></li><li><div>&quot;power to change&quot;</div></li></ul><li><div>Scripture Union</div></li><ul><li><div><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 250, 165);-evernote-highlight:true;"><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 250, 165); font-weight: bold;-evernote-highlight:true;">STOP</span></span> sending, not in country (donate $200 for all their efforts)</div></li></ul><li><div>Melbourne City Mission</div></li><ol><li><div><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 250, 165);-evernote-highlight:true;"><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 250, 165); font-weight: bold;-evernote-highlight:true;">STOP</span></span> sending, not in country</div></li></ol></ol><div><br/></div><div><span style="font-size: 24px;">Charities</span></div><ol><li><div>Save the Children</div></li><ul><li><div><span style="background-color: rgb(255,
```

One the first run of `data = processLine(data);`, all is well. If you see the commented line below it, as soon as I run that, I hit a JS error, saying something like `you can't .split() undefined`, which I understand, but I don't know why the data is `undefined`!

After the error is thrown, this is what comes out (I temporarily disabled `content = content.split(closingTag)[0];` to see what was up, that's why you see `======Services</span>======`):

```
<div id="en-note"><div>Sunday 5.6.16</div><div><br/></div><div>Money &amp; charity services I need to stop before leaving.</div><div><br/></div><div>Do this during or at latest by end of June.</div><div><br/></div><div>======Services</span>======undefined======<span style="font-size: 24px;">Christian</span></div><ol><li><div>City Bible Forum $100 support</div></li><ul><li><div><span style="font-weight: bold;">DONE</span> - June 4 &gt; <span style="font-weight: bold;">CANCELLED, TAX RECEIPT </span></div></li><li><div>&quot;ecom Sydney&quot;</div></li></ul><li><div>Youth For Christ $100 support</div></li><ul><li><div><span style="font-weight: bold;">DONE</span> - June 20 &gt; <span style="font-weight: bold;">CANCELLED, TAX RECEIPT </span></div></li><li><div>&quot;YOUTH FOR CHRIST AUSTR MITCHAM VIC&quot;</div></li></ul><li><div>Phil ministry $100 support</div></li><ul><li><div><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 250, 165);-evernote-highlight:true;">FINISH after September payment</span></div></li><li><div>&quot;power to change&quot;</div></li></ul><li><div>Scripture Union</div></li><ul><li><div><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 250, 165);-evernote-highlight:true;"><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 250, 165); font-weight: bold;-evernote-highlight:true;">STOP</span></span> sending, not in country (donate $200 for all their efforts)</div></li></ul><li><div>Melbourne City Mission</div></li><ol><li><div><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 250, 165);-evernote-highlight:true;"><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 250, 165); font-weight: bold;-evernote-highlight:true;">STOP</span></span> sending, not in country</div></li></ol></ol><div><br/></div><div><span style="font-size: 24px;">Charities</span></div><ol><li><div>Save the Children</div></li><ul><li><div><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 250, 165);-evernote-highlight:true;"><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 250, 165); font-weight: bold;-evernote-highlight:true;">STOP</span></span> sending, not in country</div></li></ul><li><div>Olivia Newton-John Foundation</div></li><ul><li><div><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 250, 165);-evernote-highlight:true;"><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 250, 165); font-weight: bold;-evernote-highlight:true;">STOP</span></span> sending, not in country</div></li></ul><li><div>Cancer Council $35 support</div></li><ul><li><div><span style="font-weight: bold;">DONE</span> - June 15 &gt; <span style="font-weight: bold;">CANCELLED, TAX RECEIPT </span></div></li></ul></ol><div><b><br/></b></div><div><b><br/></b></div><div><b><br/></b></div><div><b><br/></b></div><div><b><br/></b></div></div>
```

I had a look through and basically after the 1st HTML transformation, a bunch of data became undefined, and then the rest was intact.

Sorry it's a bit long, if you save the code in a couple of files you should be able to run this.

Not sure if I've been starring at this for too long and can't spot something obvious. Thanks a lot!

PS: I'm new to node, I could be missing something really obvious related to the way node functions on a fundamental level. I've been reading a little bit, but mainly bits and pieces to solve my current task.

Comment: How is this recursive? Also, could you post the whole error message?

Comment: @MinusFour It's recursive because I run to run `data = processLine(data);` many times to "wash" the input, basically each time removing an instance of a specific HTML bit. Error is this: `content = content.split(closingTag)[0];
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at processHTML`. So like I said, it's throwing because my data becomes `undefined`, but I don't know why my data becomes like that when I run `data = processLine(data);` the 2nd time.

Comment: That's not recursive, it would be recursive if `processLine` would call `processLine` at some point. Anyway, the problem is with the line before. You split the string but you aren't getting 2 entries as a result. So accessing the second index through `[1]` yields undefined.

Comment: Ok thanks for the recursive clarification. Actually, I turn that entire line off to avoid the JS error for the 2nd run through. I know that code works because the 1st time it does exactly what I intend. There's no difference in the data input as it attempts it the 2nd time, there's just 1 less <span> of HTML to contend with. So I expect it to work and remove another instances of <span>, it however doesn't and chokes on an undefined from where I don't know

Comment: I already told you from where `undefined` comes from. There's a problem with your search pattern logic though.  You need to find the next `</span>` after the `<span>` index position, because otherwise it will match the first `</span>` it finds in the string which can be before the specific `<span>` you are looking for. So you can do `closeTagIndex = line.indexOf(closingTag, openTagIndex)`

Comment: @MinusFour oh, that sounds spot on. I'll try that out when I get home! If it fixes it, I'll let you know! Thanks a bunch

Comment: @MinusFour yep that fixed it. If you post that as an answer I can accept it. Used this to get my HTML `var html = data.match(new RegExp(/<span style="font-size: 24px;">.*?<\/span>/))[0]`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You're only processing the line once by using an `if` statement checking for an index. Basically you compacted everything into a single `line` and checked if it had a single instance of `font-size: 24px;`, processed that, and then returned everything.

Instead you should go line by line, look for `font-size: 24px`, alter the line if necessary, and then return everything.

The following code does that ( it exits out of readline when it sees the string `close` for demonstration purposes. You'll want to remove that. )

```
// input & output
var readline = require("readline");
var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false
});
var i = 0;
var strings = [];

// HTML cleaner
function processHTML(line, openingTag, closingTag, mdStart, mdEnd) {
    var openTagIndex = line.indexOf(openingTag);
    var closeTagIndex = line.indexOf(closingTag);
    var closeTagLength = closingTag.length;
    var htmlTag = line.substring(openTagIndex, closeTagIndex + closeTagLength);

    var content = htmlTag.split(openingTag)[1];
    content = content.split(closingTag)[0];

    return line.replace(htmlTag, mdStart + content + mdEnd);
}

// process left over HTML
function processLine(lines) {
    return lines
        .map(line =>
            line.includes("font-size: 24px;")
                ? processHTML(
                        line,
                        '<span style="font-size: 24px;">',
                        "</span>",
                        "======",
                        "======"
                  )
                : line
        )
        .join("");
}

// loop through lines
rl.on("line", function(line) {
    if (line === "close") rl.close();
    strings[i] = line;
    i++;
}).on("close", function() {
    var data = strings;

    data = processLine(data);

    process.stdout.write(data);
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I was trying to do things line-by-line last time, but sometimes HTML tags (I was searching for & trying to replace as a whole) were broken over a line and so they wouldn't match (data is processed line by line), so my solution was to join it all together and then process the data repeatedly with a loop to wash it.